# Sobolev-type inequality.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $0<\alpha<n$, $1<p<q<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{\alpha}{n}$. Then:

$$\left\|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{f(y)dy}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}} \right\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C\left\| f \right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$.

Comment: Here are some helpful references http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204322/step-in-proof-of-sobolev-imbedding , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181339/compactness-and-boundedness-of-integral-operator , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178938/a-marcinkiewicz-approach

Comment: Would you mind and formulate a question?